# bluetooth module HM-15 and Arduino scanning for iBeacons

Tags: bluetooth, arduino, ibeacon, hm-10

I bought a HM-15 BLE bluetooth module and successefully connected to Arduino. I am able to sent At commands and I would like to use it for scanning for iBeacons and get their major and minor.

Using AT+DISC? I can see the beacon address but I cannot connect to it and  now I am stuck on how to retrieve major and minor

Can you help me? Here is the datasheet of the module:
http://www.elecrow.com/download/bluetooth40_en.pdf

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Bluetooth beacons do not require a connection and you read the identifiers directly from the advertisement.

Read section 19, Start a discovery scan, and learn how to read and decode the bytes in the discovered peripherals.  The exact byte layout varies for different beacon types.  For AltBeacon, an open source beacon variant, you can see the byte layout here: https://github.com/AltBeacon/spec

To decode a proprietary beacon format, you will need to learn how that beacon layout differs from the example linked above.

Comment: Hi David, thanks for the quick reply. Now it is clear to me why I do not need a connection to the beacon. However, the command AT+DISC? of section 19 returns only the name of the beacon device and the address ...I went through all the datasheet of the module: how to retrieve the all the bytes of the discovered beacon?

Comment: Reading the documentation more I do not see anywhere that this device will return you the full bytes of received advertisements.  Unfortunately, this probably means you cannot use it to detect beacons.

Answer (score 0):

Old question, but just for the record, you can use AT-DISI?

This will scan for beacons, including iBeacons and also AltBeacons. The response from HM-10 will include RSSI for each.

PS: I'm assuming HM-15 and HM-10 operate the same way. Probably not exactly a fully reasonable assumption.